# Dropzone.js V.4 with CakePHP V. 2.5.7

Tags: cakephp, dropzone.js, cakephp-2.5, cakephp-2.x

I have a view with the dropbox called index.ctp:

```
        echo $this->Form->create('', array('url' => array('controller' => 'vouchers', 'action' => 'uploads'), 'novalidate' => true, 'role' => 'form', 'class' => 'dropzone', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data', 'id' => 'my-awesome-dropzone'));
        echo '<div class="dropzone-previews"></div>';
        echo $this->Form->input('Voucher.file', array('type' => 'file', 'label' => false, 'div' => 'fallback', 'class' => false, 'multiple' => true));
        echo $this->Form->end();
```

In my controller 'VouchersController.php' is the upload function als follows:

```
public function uploads() {
    $this->Security->validatePost = false;
    $this->Security->enabled = false;
    $this->Security->csrfCheck = false;
    $data = array(
        'Voucher' => array(
                    'description' => 'xx'
            )
        );
    $this->Voucher->save($data);
}
```

It seems that the dropzone.js works correctly. Files appears to uploaded and a checkmark is setted in the preview. If I change the url from the Form->create, then it appears an error in the preview. This says me that the url to the controller is working.

If I call the action 'uploads' directly in my browser, it is working -> a new entry in the Voucher table is there (only for test purposes). I will implement the file saving when the action is working so far.

But the (ajax) call from the dropzone.js is not working. Nothing happens in my database. I think the upload action is not called because no db entry is there after dropping files to my dropzone.

Thank you for any help in this case.

Please leave a reply if any information is missing for your help.
Ivo

Answer (score 0):

I found the error by myself. I had to add the following line in  `beforeFilter()`:

```
 $this->Security->unlockedActions = array('action');
```

This disables `SecurityComponent` for `action`.